# Permission Denied (public key)

Tags: 12.04, server

I have a Ubuntu server and another Ubuntu desktop... When I used `ssh abc@123.456.78.9` it just shows Permission Denied (publickey). I have already set these to `PasswordAuthentication no` and `UsePAM no`, but even then I'm not able to connect the server... Please help me on this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `PasswordAuthentication` to `no` you can login only by using keys. If you didn't set up keys properly it denies you the access with exactly that error (`Permission Denied (publickey)`). You either need to reactivate passwords or set up public key authentication (a lot of tutorials available for that).